# Failed to deserialize data for topic to protobuf sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I can consume produced protobuf message data from kafka topic using different tool like conduktor. However, when I try to poll data using JdbcSinkConnector, it throws the exception like

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
> deserializing Protobuf message

Please take a look at the following error detail when I call kafka-connect api as follows

URL : `http://localhost:8083/connectors?expand=info&expand=status`

**JSON Response and trace**

```
{
   "sink_postgres_03_proto":{
      "info":{
         "name":"sink_postgres_03_proto",
         "config":{
            "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "connection.password":"54321",
            "topics":"order-messages",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
            "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
            "auto.evolve":"true",
            "connection.user":"postgres",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
            "name":"sink_postgres_03_proto",
            "auto.create":"true",
            "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CallHistoryService",
            "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter",
            "insert.mode":"insert",
            "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
         },
         "tasks":[
            {
               "connector":"sink_postgres_03_proto",
               "task":0
            }
         ],
         "type":"sink"
      },
      "status":{
         "name":"sink_postgres_03_proto",
         "connector":{
            "state":"RUNNING",
            "worker_id":"kafka-connect:8083"
         },
         "tasks":[
            {
               "id":0,
               "state":"FAILED",
               "worker_id":"kafka-connect:8083",
               "trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:196)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:472)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic order-messages to Protobuf: \n\tat io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter.toConnectData(ProtobufConverter.java:123)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\t... 13 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Protobuf message for id 1\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n\tat java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)\n\tat java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:272)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:660)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:642)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:217)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:291)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.java:117)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.java:235)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(ProtobufConverter.java:163)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter.toConnectData(ProtobufConverter.java:107)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:122)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:472)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\n"
            }
         ],
         "type":"sink"
      }
   }
}
```

Please advice

Thanks you!

Comment: Postgres and the Schema Registry are running on the same machine? The error seems to say the HTTP request to the registry failed

Comment: I updated my json response along with error trace. Yes, Postgres and Schema registry are running on the same machine!

Comment: So if you go to http://localhost:8081/subjects, you do get a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the `trace` node and convert the `\n` and `\t` to newlines and tabs you get a readable stack trace with shows the problem:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic order-messages to Protobuf: 
    at io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter.toConnectData(ProtobufConverter.java:123)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Protobuf message for id 1
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The error is `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`  and means that either (a) you've misconfigured the location of your Schema Registry or (b) the Schema Registry is not running